# Low quality playback in XBMC

Tags: vlc-media-player, kodi

I have VLC on my pc which I used to use for watching shows, but I've recently switched to using XBMC so I can stream things/control my pc from my phone, but I've noticed that XBMC has a much lower quality of video playback compared to VLC (MKV's and MP4's). Can anyone thing why this could be?

Windows Media Player/XBMC

[image: WMP/XBMC]

VLC

[image: VLC]

I'm not sure how well you can tell on the pictures but on WMP/XBMC, the edges are a lot blurrier and less near, and the colours look blockier.

XBMC Video output

[image]

Comment: What operating system are you using? Can you elaborate a bit more on "lower quality"?

Comment: Windows 7 x64, I'll get some screenshots now

Comment: my best guess is that XBMC is either using a different codec or a different filter or a combination of the two.

Comment: I assume you are using the latest release of XBMC? Also could you give us an output of the video information while it's playing in XBMC (I believe it's the `o` key to activate it).

Comment: I'm using Frodo, and I'll add the output screenshot in my post in a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by video driver settings. You must disable "edge enhancement" feature in your video card preferences. I've attached below screenshots for NVIDIA and ATI video cards, taken from preferences window where you can disable this feature. Set your preferences as visible on pictures.

ATI video preferences:

[image: ATI video preferences]

NVIDIA video preferences:

[image: NVIDIA video preferences]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer :) fix the problem for me. I'd upvote twice if I could :P

Comment: I'm glad I helped.